# Show that the chromatic number of a certain graph is at most $5$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I was studying graph theory and stumbled across the following question:

Consider a simple graph $G$ with the following property: any pair of cycles of odd length
the graph intersect (namely every pair of cycles of odd length share at least one
vertex). You may assume that the graph has at least two cycles of odd length. Show
that the chromatic number $χ(G)$ of the graph $G$ is at most $5$.

I'm thinking of solving this via induction: asserting a base case while removing an odd cycle from the graph each time. However, I'm not totally sure how to proceed. Any insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

We give a proper coloring of $G$ where the colors are $a,b,c,d,e$. Remove from $G$ any odd cycle $C$ *of minimum length*; the vertices as well as the edges. Then as every odd cycle contains a vertex in $C$, the the resulting graph $G \setminus V(C)$ has no odd cycles and thus is bipartite. So properly color $G \setminus V(C)$ with $2$ colors $a$ and $b$. Then properly color $C$ with the remaining $3$ colors $c$, $d$, $e$.

This indeed gives a proper coloring of $G$ where the colors are $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$. Indeed, to check that the coloring is proper, it only remains to check that two vertices in $V(C)$ that are not adjacent to each other in the cycle $C$ itself, are also not adjacent in the larger graph $G$. However, that $C$ is an odd cycle of minimum length guarantees that indeed, $C$ has no chords. For if $C$ did, observe that there would be two smaller cycles and one of those smaller would be of *odd* length. So the coloring holds up as proper.

Comment: It seems to me that your last statement about coloring of cycle $C$ needs a neater proof. The point is that the vertices of cycle $C$ can also be connected by other edges of graph $G$.

Comment: @kabenyuk you are correct. Fixed.

Comment: Yes, everything is fine now.

Comment: Awesome, this makes sense, thanks.